# How can I stop iOS devices (iPad) reading telephone numbers as contact links in ASCX?

Tags: ios, ascx

I'm working in ACSX (template for DNN), I have looked thoroughly for a fix but I have only found solutions that can work in a html document like this...

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

However ACSX doesn't include the  tag so it doesn't allow for this solution. Is there anyway around using Javascript or even in the ASCX itself?

Answer (score 0):

Just done this in the DNN settings for each page, there is a text field for all your metatags.